# Magento 2 PWA Venia enable Maintenance mode for Storefront

Tags: magento2, pwa-studio, venia

I have **Magento 2** backend with **PWA venia** storefront.
I need to enable **maintenance mode** for storefront or **display sitedown** page on storefront.

How to do it? When I run *bin/magento maintenance:enable* storefront still working with "Fetch data errors".